# Why is subprocess ignoring PATH, and how can I change this?

Tags: python, linux, path, subprocess

I need to change which program is called by a Python application. Unfortunately *I cannot change the Python code*. I can only change the calling environment (in particular, `PATH`). But unfortunately Python’s subprocess module seems to ignore `PATH` (at least under certain circumstances).

**How can I force Python to respect `PATH` when searching which binary to invoke?**

To illustrate the problem, here’s an MVCE. The actual Python application is using `subprocess.check_output(['nvidia-smi', '-L'])`, but the following simplified code shows the same behaviour.

Create `test.py`:

```py
import os
from subprocess import run

run(['which', 'whoami'])
run(['/usr/bin/env', 'whoami'])
run(['whoami'])

os.execvp('whoami', ['whoami'])
```

Now create a local `whoami` script and execute `test.py`:

```sh
echo 'echo foobar' >whoami
chmod +x whoami
PATH=.:$PATH python3 test.py
```

On my system<sup>1</sup> this prints:

```
./whoami
foobar
konrad
konrad
```

I *expect* this code to always print `foobar` instead of `konrad`.

My MVCE includes the `os.execvp` call because [the `subprocess` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) states that

> On POSIX, the class uses `os.execvp()`-like behavior to execute the child program.

Needless to say, the *actual* `execvp` POSIX API, called from C, *does* respect `PATH`, so this is a Python specific issue.

---

<sup>1</sup> Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, Python 3.6.9.

Comment: if I put `#!/bin/sh` at the beginning of your `whoami` script I get your expected behaviour, is omitting that deliberate?  running it without gives `ENOEXEC (Exec format error)` on the script

Comment: I can reproduce the problem and adding `#!/bin/sh` fixes it.  Which makes sense - in `strace` I see `execve("./whoami", ...) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)` because of the missing shebang kernel can't execute the file - so `/usr/bin/whoami` is chosen.

Comment: @KamilCuk note that strace uses `execve` while OP appears to be deliberately using `execvp`. the latter which should attempt to interpret using `/bin/sh` if it gets `ENOEXEC` when executing directly

Comment: [os.py#L608 _execvpe()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py#L608) I guess a `except (ENOEXEC): exec("sh", file...)` is missing

Comment: @SamMason It wasn’t *deliberate*, but I thought it shouldn’t be *necessary* (and isn’t for POSIX’ `execvp`!). But that indeed fixes my issue, and if you write it up as an answer I can accept that! I’m still curious why it’s required here when it isn’t for the POSIX function (though thinking about it now I’m more surprised that the POSIX function *doesn’t* require it).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807937/subprocess-popen-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-in-python covers this quite well. Seems python can't tell what kind of executable it is, or if it's a binary or shell script etc etc. setting chmod +x is only the half the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per my comment, this is due to Python's implementation of [`execvp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execvp) not being consistent with POSIX [`execvp`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) semantics.  in particular Python [doesn't respond to `ENOEXEC` errors](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4f28f75deefc6e8f65694f96f1a40b0a26fc385d/Lib/os.py#L587) by interpreting the file as a shell script and needs an explicit shebang.

creating the file as:

```sh
printf '#!/bin/sh\necho foobar\n' > ./whoami
```

causes things to work as expected

note that this has been known about for a while: https://bugs.python.org/issue19948

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
echo 'echo foobar' >whoami
chmod +x whoami
```

is not running correctly.

Python is not picking it up a executable, even though though the execute bit is set, it doesn't know it needs to run bash first, to execute, thus is skips in on the path and runs the original whoami which is pathed /usr/bin/whoami

adding shebang

```
echo "#!/bin/sh" > whoami
echo 'echo foobar' >> whoami
chmod +x whoami
```

On Unix-style systems (including Linux/OS X), the shebang line—as it’s called—tells the loader (or kernel, or occasionally shell) which program to use to run the file. At its most basic, you’d specify a path to the python interpreter.

i suspect if you ./whoami (with execute permission set), the shell is doing some extra magic so you don't have to type /bin/sh $PWD/whoami

if you do

chmod -x whoami

you can use the special

. ./whoami (tell the shell to execute it as a shell script).

note that execvp should use /bin/sh rather than bash. also . ./whoami will depend on what shell you happen to be using, most will "source" the file rather than executing it in another process (i.e. changes to environment, working directory, etc will remain)

If no shebang or executable header, the shell simply uses itself as the default interpreter (but only when invoked via ./whoami; . ./whoami is different, it sources the file, regardless of whether it’s executable).

The confusing nature of execvp (POSIX, not Python) apparently also does this. Python fails in this case because os.execvp actually does not call execvp under the hood, it similarities  are just in name.

Comment: note that `execvp` should use `/bin/sh` rather than bash.  also `. ./whoami` will depend on what shell you happen to be using, most will "source" the file rather than executing it in another process (i.e. changes to environment, working directory, etc will remain)

Comment: Yep, the shell simply uses itself as the default interpreter if no shebang or executable header is given (but only when invoked via `./whoami`; `. ./whoami` is different, it *sources* the file, regardless of whether it’s executable). What confused me is that `execvp` (POSIX, not Python) apparently *also* does this. And Python fails because `os.execvp` actually *does not* call `execvp`.

Comment: Great comments, i will add that to my answer.. thanks @SamMason and Konrad RuDolph