# Problem with open a .sh file with Python:not found

Tags: python, shell

I have to open a .sh file with a python GUI developed with PyQt5. So I implemented the command:

```
def function_openSH(self):
    subprocess.call('chmod u+x ./script_open.sh', shell=True)
    subprocess.call('./script_open.sh', shell=True)
```

It gives me: `./script_open.sh: 5: source: not found`. Why?

Comment: @TforV What’s inside `script_open.sh`? That’s where the error occurs. Can you run the file manually on the command line?

Comment: `./` means "this directory". It is likely that the subprocess you start has a different idea of what that means.

Comment: @BoarGules No, see my comment reply to S3DEV.

Comment: Dear all, the script works but it gives the same error: very strange

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes I can but that's not the problem

Comment: @TforV What do you mean by that? How can the script work *and* give an error? — **Show the script**. Otherwise we can’t help you.

Comment: @TforV : `source` is not a valid command in POSIX shell. Use `.` instead.

Comment: Dear @KonradRudolph into the .sh there are two python  script to be called

Comment: ....but I solved with @glenn jackman

Comment: @TforV : FYI, you can find a list of all builtin shell commands [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14). The command you are looking for is described on that page under the "name" _dot - execute commands in the current environment_.

Answer (score 3):

subprocess with `shell=True` specifically uses `/bin/sh`. If this is not a symlink to bash, then you may be using a POSIX compliant shell (such as [dash](/questions/tagged/dash)), then the `source` command is not available:

```sh
$ cat > foo.sh
echo hello world

$ bash -c 'source ./foo.sh'
hello world

$ /bin/sh -c 'source ./foo.sh'
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found

$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug  7  2020 /bin/sh -> dash

$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('source ./foo.sh', shell=True)
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
127
```

---

Since you explicitly made your script executable, use `shell=False`

---

Or, use the POSIX sh `.` command instead of the bash-specific `source`.

```sh
>>> subprocess.call('. ./foo.sh', shell=True)
hello world
0
```

Comment: Cor. Another day, another command I had assumed to be part of POSIX I learn is actually a bashism.

Comment: @glennjackman: I'm pretty sure that the OP knowingly does use a pure POSIX shell: He tagged his question simply with _shell_, and never mentions a different shell (such as ksh,...) anywhere.

Comment: @user1934428 Exceedingly unlikely. If OP *knowingly* used a pure POSIX shell they’d have known to add the shebang line. Furthermore, they clearly *do* use a different shell, since their script uses bashisms.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you did not specify which shell to use e.g. `#!/bin/bash` or that you don't define the explicit path of the `.sh` file.

Comment: Yeah, thats true, but I kinda remember there were issues with .sh when not specifying which shell to use, were /bin/sh was used. That issue produced a ton of broken scripts in Ubuntu.

Comment: That’s definitely true, and Python’s `execvp` call differs from the POSIX API’s (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/62893701/1968). But this isn’t relevant here: OP’s code *works* with a script without shebang line if all it does is invoke `source` on an existing file.