# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error when calling subprocess.Popen on an exe file

Tags: python, subprocess, exe

I'm calling `subprocess.Popen` on an `exe` file in [this script](https://github.com/PolicyEngine/openfisca-us/blob/6ae4e65f6883be598f342c445de1d52430db6b28/openfisca_us/tools/dev/taxsim/generate_taxsim_tests.py#L146), and it [throws](https://gist.github.com/MaxGhenis/b0eb890232363ed30efc1be505e1f257#file-gistfile1-txt-L249):

> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/maxghenis/PolicyEngine/openfisca-us/openfisca_us/tools/dev/taxsim/taxsim35.exe'

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30551364/1840471) to [subprocess.Popen(): OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26807937/1840471) suggests adding `#!/bin/sh` to the top of the shell script. What's an analog to that for calling an exe instead of a shell script?

I'm on a Mac, and the file it's running is https://taxsim.nber.org/stata/taxsim35/taxsim35-unix.exe.

Comment: Which operating system are you running? Which operating system and architecture are the executable built for?

Comment: If you're on a UNIXy platform (or at least have UNIXy tools installed), you can use the `file` command to answer the second subset of questions there.

Comment: ...in general, though, this means that your operating system can't run the kind of executable you have in that location. (If it's a Windows executable and you're on Linux, it's possible that you might be able to get it to run using WINE configured through binfmt_misc; but that's not a sure thing unless the program in question has been tested to be compatible with WINE's reimplementation of the win32 API; if it's a 64-bit Windows executable and you're on 32-bit Windows, you're going to need to either recompile the executable or find compatible hardware).

Comment: Anyhow -- because this question can't be answered without details that aren't included (after having checked the repository and verified that the `.exe` file isn't committed to the source -- though even if it were, that wouldn't answer the subset of questions relating to your runtime environment), I'm voting-to-close as lacking a [mre]. Ping me when you update the question and I'll be glad to retract if it's in a fully answerable state.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I edited the question to specify that I'm on a Mac and the file is https://taxsim.nber.org/stata/taxsim35/taxsim35-unix.exe. I can try to make a more minimal example but I'm not too familiar with subprocess (didn't write this code) so if you see anything based on just this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `subprocess` can't make a program work on an operating system it isn't compiled for; let me download that file and see if I can make heads or tails of it.

Comment: (...or you could answer that yourself, by adding the output of `file taxsim35-unix.exe` to your question)

Comment: ...okay: `file taxsim35-unix.exe` emits `taxsim35-unix.exe: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=c5496d77cb56826e0754b07aba43bbf3753d34d0, with debug_info, not stripped`. So it's very misleadingly misnamed to imply that it's a generic "unix" executable; it's specifically a _Linux_ executable (for 64-bit Intel-compatible CPUs), and not expected to work on Mac.

Comment: If a Mac is all you have, I'd suggest looking at your options for virtual machines about now.

Comment: BTW, you might try running the program _without_ using Python at all. (If you can't run it from a shell command line, that gives you a pretty good hint you won't be able to run it any other way either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess` can only start programs that your operating system knows how to execute.

Your `taxsim35-unix.exe` is a Linux executable. MacOS cannot run them.

You'll need to either use a Linux machine to run this executable (real or virtual), or get a version compiled for Mac. https://back.nber.org/stata//taxsim35/taxsim35-osx.exe is likely to be the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with the developers of taxsim for a while.  I believe that the .exe files generated by taxsim were originally msdos only and then moved to Linux.  They're not intended to be run by MacOS.  I don't know if they ever released the FORTRAN code that generates them so that they can be run on MacOS.  Your best bet for running taxsim (since there's no close open-source substitute) is to spin up an AWS or other Linux server.

Comment: There may be an older FreeBSD version if that's helpful (probably not).  I remember helping making the code compile on FreeBSD.  Contact the NBER and Dan Feenberg -- they're responsible to calls for help.